# What specie of flying insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The insect pictured below just flown into my room. I live in Central Europe (Poland), it is about evening now. The thing is about 1,5 cm in length (not sure about this, I was too focused on driving it out). Its white stripe on abdomen seemed to be translucent. What is this insect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pellucid fly, a species of hover fly. scientific name: *Volucella pellucens*

https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/pellucid-fly

Comment: Thanks. But isn't *Gemeine waldschwebfliege* a German name? I am not a biologist, but I thought those scientific names are always Latin-based.

Comment: my bad, I don't know why but my webpage translated the species scientific name into german which has never happened before so I didn't notice. I just changed it to its latin scientific name. .